# SCSS Partials for .css files without changing the filename

Tags: css, sass, codekit

I'm looking for ways to optimize my WordPress instance. The theme has about 8-10 CSS files that are rendered in the `functions.php`. Consequently, I do not want to change any file names because that would mean that I have to hack the theme and I want to keep that to a bare minimum.

I want to use SCSS to combine these CSS files into one CSS file and include the new file in the theme instead. When I try...

```
@import "style.css"; 
@import "reset.css";
@import "shortcodes-styles.css";
```

It renders as

```
@import url(style.css);
@import url(reset.css);
@import url(shortcodes-styles.css);
```

How can I get SCSS to import the CSS as partials without changing the file names? I'm also using CodeKit if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.  Sass only compiles Sass files:  https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/556

Comment: That's unfortunate but I'm happy there seems to be a solution coming down the pipe.