# SASS: normalize.css works, but does not show up in compiled CSS file?

Tags: css, sass, normalize-css

I am just taking my first steps into the SASS-world. I set up everything, created a new project and downloaded the SASS port of `normalize.css`.

Inside the folder that holds all my SASS files, I have a folder called "normalize". That holds a file called `normalize.scss`, that holds a mixin that again imports some other mixins that contain the actual CSS-code.
On top of my `screen.scss` I simply have `@import "normalize/normalize";`.

`screen.scss` is compiled into `screen.css`, which is used by my `index.html`. Taking a look at that page in the browser, the normalize has taken effect. But when I look at `screen.css`, I don't see the normalize code.

To make sure I am importing/loading the correct files, I pasted this on top of `normalize.scss`: `/*! normalize.css v2.1.1 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */`.

As this comment does show up in `screen.css`, I know that I am using the right files, but still: Is it normal that the actual normalize CSS-code does not show up in `screen.css` but still takes effect in the browser? How is this supposed to work?

Comment: If it is working your CSS must be linked in some way to the HTML file; Sass is very powerful but not that much. :D Are you using it in RoR? Assets pipeline is sometimes a weird thing. **Any link or jsfiddle to have a look?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCSS Partials for .css files without changing the filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467410/scss-partials-for-css-files-without-changing-the-filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was really stupid from me. I've written `@import "normalize/normalize";`, but after that I of course need to include it like `@include normalize` where 'normalize' is the mixin's name. oh well!